# Best version control for salesforce -eclipse and Mavens mate

Tags: code, git, versioning, github

Which is the best version control for force.com projects. Currently we are not using any version control and we are planning to follow some practices. We predominantly use eclipse and Mavens mate. We though the gitlab (a local version of github) is a good versioning system. Is there anyother version controls that works well with Mavens mate and eclipse?

Thanks
Akash

Answer (score 6):

I've used Subversion (SVN) and Git on Force.com projects. Either will work, but click around in the cool Github UI for a few minutes e.g. https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura (this is some of Salesforce's open source) and I suggest you won't want to use anything else. Follow the links in Jenny B's answer for the various other points of comparison or Google for more.

So if I was starting out afresh, I'd go for Git and specifically Github. (Sorry this is a subjective view not a view based on a quantitative assessment of all the options.) If your Force.com orgs that contain your source code are are in the cloud why wouldn't you have your code repository in the cloud?

The [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) tooling for Git is part of the core Eclipse distributions now too.

**PS** Using Git opens the possibility of making use of the [Gerrit Code Review](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) tool or release management tools such as [Copado](http://copa.do/).

Comment: If you want an example of a GitHub repository used for managed package development, you can check out https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus which has worked out really well for us.  We use feature branches to isolate all development, Pull Requests to review and merge feature branches, Releases to track our release tags and release notes, and the commit status api to flag build status on all commits.  Another advantage of GitHub is the number of tools which integrate with it to provide cloud based alternatives to setting up your own Jenkins for CI such as Codeship and CircleCI

Answer (score 2):

I use Subversion with Eclipse, I haven't used anything else so I can't really compare it but there is a lot of information out there on how to use it with Eclipse. [Here](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2013/03/working-forcecom-ide-and-subversion-svn) is one blog on it. Github has an [article](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-differences-between-svn-and-git) explaining the differences between the two, there are a lot of older discussions about it also on the stackoverflow. Another article on the dzone breaks down the differences [here](http://agile.dzone.com/articles/version-control-git-vs-svn). Being new to version control in general, I have been able to use SVN without any issues.