# Team Foundation Server as source control for Salesforce Project?

Tags: code, git, developer-productivity, version-control, sourcecontrol

Does anybody has experience on using Team Foundation Server as source control for Salesforce project?

We are currently using Git but management wants to start using TFS as source control going forward as other .NET developers in the company are already using TFS and they do not want to invest again in Git.

I found online articles about Salesforce and TFS Integration like posting data from salesforce to TFS but nothing about using TFS as source control for Salesforce in contrast there are so many articles about using Git as source control for salesforce. Although I found a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/835353/are-tfs-and-salesforce-compatible) posted by somebody on a different site but there is no proper answer so I am trying here if anybody knows the answer.

**Note**

1. I am well aware of the posting rules on this site and I hope my question does not violate any of the forum guidelines. If you guys think otherwise, Please feel free to close this question :)
2. This [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/best-version-control-for-salesforce-eclipse-and-mavens-mate) is some what similar to what I am asking here but it does not mention anything about TFS..so please don't close this question as duplicate :)

Comment: I hvn't used TFS with SF, but I know TFS has Git support, and since you are already using Git you should be able to migrate easily. good luck.

Comment: I'm in the same situation and would love to know if anyone's got experience with this.